# Styling of Prism PageDialogService with AppThemeBindings

Tags: maui, prism

I am looking for an efficient way to style all my IPageDialogService usages in my .NET Maui app. Currently, I use the AppThemeBinding for all styling which are affected by light and dark modes. This works fine, but all my IPageDialogService references all still on a white background when using the dark mode.

In the official documentation isn't a dedicated styling part on the IPageDialogService. https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/dialogs/pagedialogs.html

It would be favorable to style the dialogs globally, all other styles are mostly in the styles.xaml file. Is there a specific TargetType for the IPageDialogService or a best practice for styling the dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out you can't style the dialogs via xaml. After some digging in the source code of prism and maui, we discovered, that in the end, the platform-specific dialogs are called and rendered; hence you must set the correct platform theme on theme switching in the app.

For Android the `using AppCompatAlertDialog = AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog;` is used.

```
#if ANDROID
            AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = Current.UserAppTheme switch
            {
                AppTheme.Light => AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo,
                AppTheme.Dark => AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes,
                _ => AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightFollowSystem
            };
#elif IOS
            Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController().OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = Current.UserAppTheme switch
            {
                AppTheme.Light => UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light,
                AppTheme.Dark => UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark,
                _ => UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Unspecified
            };
#endif
```

Confirmed in this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6092

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.